# How can I use the Data View panel to open the sqlite file?

Tags: python, pycharm

In my PyCharm CE, there is a DataView, I saw some developer use it to open the sqlite db. But I never success.

[image]

And the other question is, can I use the DataView to open MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

For CE: 
[image]

And then:
[image]

For Pro:

I have this Plugin installed:

[image]

And it gives my this view which I can use to connect to most databases:

[image]

Comment: How to install that plugin?

Comment: @244boy I have just realized that I am running pro. the alternative is https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator